# Reverse array pointer in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to learn pointers with arrays.
I want to do this with the function below:

```
int* ArrayManipulator(int* arrayPoiner, const int size)
```

to reverse the array list:

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* ArrayManipulator(int* arrayPoiner, const int size)
{
    int i=0;
    int tt[size];
    for (i=0;i<=size;i++)
    {
        cout<<arrayPoiner[size-i]<<endl;
        cout<<&arrayPoiner[size-i]<<endl;

        tt[i]=arrayPoiner[size-i];
    }
    return tt;
}


int main()
{
    int t[]={1,2};
    int *ReversedArray;
    ReversedArray = ArrayManipulator(t,1);
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        cout<< ReversedArray[i]<<endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I am receiving error at `cout<< ReversedArray[i];`
`cout<< &ReversedArray[i];` is printing the address of the value but I am unable to print the value - codeblocks error out there

EDIT Code:
[image]

I want the final two lines to be 2 and 1, where am I going wrong on code.

Comment: What is the error? What is your question?

Comment: you should get SEGV , and tt should be on the heap, and you also forgot to return the pointer.

Comment: `ArrayManipulator` returns a pointer to an array that was allocated on the stack; this invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are also passing the size of the array - 1 to your function and then declaring int tt[size] or tt[1] so that tt has only 1 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return the pointer to the array that has been allocated on the heap:

Modify your method signature:

```
int** ArrayManipulator(int* arrayPoiner, const int size)
```

Allocate on the heap:

```
int **tt = new int*[size];
```

return the pointer to the array;

```
return tt;
```

and modify your calls such that:

```
int **ReversedArray = ArrayManipulator(t,1);
```

and to output do this:

```
cout<< *ReversedArray[i];
```

Don't forget to delete the space allocated with:

```
  delete [] ReversedArray;
```

Comment: I was beating my head for this - now need to learn more on ** pointers :(

Comment: Thank you very much for the time and knowledge.

Comment: Why are you using a **?

Comment: @Bob__ the OP modified the question a bit since this was answered. In the original version he was actually using a array to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Function ArrayManipulator returns nothing. So the program is already has undefined behaviour.

I think what you want to get is the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int * ArrayManipulator( const int *source, size_t n, int *dest )
{
    dest = dest + n;

    while ( n-- ) *--dest = *source++;

    return dest;        
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 2;

    int a[N] = { 1, 2 };
    int b[N];

    int * ReversedArray = ArrayManipulator( a, N, b );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cout << ReversedArray[i] << ' ';
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` declared in header `<algorithm>` that does a similar work. If you want to reverse an array "in place" then you can use another standard algorithm `std::reverse`.

Comment: that is actually a very nice solution to this problem, if one wants to avoid heap allocation.